# Wine installation messed up unity?

Tags: unity, installation, 12.04, wine

the exit, minimize, and window size buttons are gone (for ubuntu main programs) in the top left of screen and the entire black bar with the buttons when in windowed mode is gone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Compiz is decorating the windows.

**1)** Install [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager),

**2)** Open ccsm (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**3)** Got to "Effects" and check "Window Decoration":

[image]

Comment: Great to know that :-)